# Can no stop robot Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a thread which has a boolean value called terminate- when it is set to true the thread should stop- the problem is when i do set it to false it does no register with the thread? how do I directly set the value of terminated to true in my thread? thanks

```
            btnPlayback.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            Playback function = new Playback(list, progBar, settings);
            Thread playback = new Thread(function);
            if (recording == true) {
                btnRecord.setText("Record");
                recording = false;
            }
            if (playing == false) {
                playing = true;
                btnPlayback.setText("Stop");
                playback.start();
            } else { 
                playing = false; 
                btnPlayback.setText("Playback");
                function.terminate();
            }
        });
```

this is in the Thread's class

```
     public void terminate() {
         terminated = true;
    }
```

Should prevent statements like this

```
        for (InputValue i: list) {
            if (terminated == false) {
```

Comment: Is `terminated` `volatile`?  Maybe use an `AtomicBoolean` instead?

Comment: Since you say the ``Thread`` has the method ``terminate()``, it probably is not ``function.terminate();`` but ``playback.terminate();``. Otherwise it's hard to get the problem since not all relevant code is shown.

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions

The Thread `playback` is responsible for playing the media (what ever type) on a different thread. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time.

### Problem

You start the playback-Thread with the Thread's start method. That's correct. But you try to stop it with a call to function.terminate(). As I don't exactly know the context of terminate(), I'm not able to help you here, but in a more general wise.

A bigger Problem might be, that you create a new Thread and a new Playback Object each time you click at the button. From the following code this seems to be wrong.

### Solution

A Thread can be `interrupted`! So you need to say the thread, that if someone clicked the "Stop" button, to interrupt it's work and finish the thread.

Move the Thread and the Playback variables to the outside of this block.

In your `btnPlayback.setOnMouseClicked` method, do the following on the thread object:

```
playback.interrupt();
```

But in your Runnable Playback you have to watch for interrupts. In your Runnable you need something that proves the flag interrupted state, like:

```
   if (Thread.interrupted()) {
      throw new InterruptedException();
    }
```

The exception then needs to be catched and your terminate could be set to true. Because there is no more else to do, the run can return:

```
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    terminate = true;
    return;
  }
```

A possible solution is shown down below. But I had to make a lot of assumptions because you haven't cleared all out. Maybe you want to read a bit more of Threading, then visit this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {

  Playback function = null;
  Thread playback = null;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
      if (function == null) {
        function = new Playback(list, progBar, settings);
      }
      if (playback == null) {
        playback = new Thread(function);
      }
      if (recording == true) {
        btnRecord.setText("Record");
        recording = false;
      }
      if (playing == false) {
        playing = true;
        btnPlayback.setText("Stop");
        playback.start();
      } else {
        playing = false;
        btnPlayback.setText("Playback");
        playback.interrupt();
        function = null;
        playback = null;
      }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  static class Playback implements Runnable {

    boolean terminate = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        // playing music or something else and ask sometimes, if this is interrupted
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
          throw new InterruptedException();
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        terminate = true;
        return;
      }
    }

  }
}
```